# Simple javascript fetch to php

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

here is my code:

```
        let jsobject = [];
        jsobject.push({
            "fname": fname,
            "lname": lname,
            "uname": uname,
            "email": email,
            "pw": pw1.value,

        });
        let str = [];
        str.push(encodeURIComponent("data") + "=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(jsobject)));
        str = str.join("&");

        let url = window.location.href;
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            body: str,
        }).then(data => {
            return data;
        }).then(json => {
            console.log(json)
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);

        });
```

And my php code:

```
echo $_REQUEST['str'];
```

My fetch is sucessfull, but i don't get any result from my php echo. Anyone that can help?

Comment: We'd need to see the PHP part too. Notice, that the data you send, is not what you think it is, you need to iterate the object, and then encode the individual keys and values.

Comment: the php code is just echo $_REQUEST['str'];

Comment: You never pass anything which could be interpreted to `str` at the back-end. You could `echo $_POST['data']`, then you'll see what went wrong, when you formed the body for the request.

Comment: It just says "Notice: Undefined index: str in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\register.php on line 108" So it doesn't even get the request

Comment: Again: you never send anything which could be interpreted `str`. `str` is defined in the JS only. Check the echo adviced on my comment above.

Comment: i did, i get the same error but "data" instead of "str"

Comment: When you fix the value for the body as described above, and in fetch promise chain do this: `fetch(...).then(data => data.json()).then(json => {...})`, your code should work, providing your server returns valid JSON. If the server doesn't find the posted values, that's a place for a new question, introduce your server-side code, used frameworks/libraries, and show also the JS snippet how you're fetching the data.